# How to send next() in a callback function

Tags: python, node.js, rest, express, npm

Here i want to send the next() when my data is received from the python script but i am getting Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

module.exports = (req, res, next)=>{
let myPythonScriptPath = 'encrypt.py';
const pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);
let path = req.file.path;    
pyshell.send(path);


pyshell.on("message", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    req.filepath = data;
    next();
})

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
});
}
```

---

but it is working when i put next() at the end of code but then my req.filepath is undefined

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

module.exports = (req, res, next)=>{
let myPythonScriptPath = 'encrypt.py';
const pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);
let path = req.file.path;    
pyshell.send(path);


pyshell.on("message", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    req.filepath = data;
})

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
});

next();
}
```

What i want is to store the data coming from python script in req.filepath which is to be sent to next middleware. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using callback methodolgy this can be acheived by sending the result of the function in callback().(Here callback is next)

The code is given below:

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

module.exports = function (req, res, next){
try{
    let myPythonScriptPath = '/home/anmolmiddha/Projects/coreshare/server/api/python/encrypt.py';
    const pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);
    let path = req.file.path;
    pyshell.send(path);
    pyshell.on("message", function(data){
    });

    pyshell.end(function (err, rslt) {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else{
            req.filepath = JSON.stringify(path).split('"')[1];
            next(rslt);
        }
    });
}
catch(error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Invalid token Auth failed"
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this behavior due to the order of asynchronous tasks, which I've enumerated below in the comments.  The execution doesn't necessarily happen in the same sequence that the code is written, so, you're either trying to modify a request/response *after* the PyShell command has already been sent (case #1 above), or Express has already moved on to the next middleware before `req.filepath` has been set (case #2 above).

```js
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  let myPythonScriptPath = 'encrypt.py';
  const pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);
  let path = req.file.path;
  pyshell.send(path); // 1) Send the command

  // 3) This anonymous function is invoked, but it's
  // too late -- the command has already been sent
  // and has continued on to the next middleware.
  pyshell.on("message", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    // This will be undefined in the next middleware
    // because it moved on before it was actually set.
    req.filepath = data;
  })

  // 4) This anonymous function gets run last.
  pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
  });

  next() // 2) Tell Express to continue on to the next middleware.
}
```

Do you have other middleware before or after this one that is trying to modify or send an HTTP response?

Comment: yes i have middleware before and after this one. So, how i can make the response to wait to proceed to next middleware untill the callback is called ?